# How to disable back button on a progressive web app

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, back-button

I need help with the famous back-button-problem in an progressive-web-app.

I want to disable the back funtion of the back-button on the android smartphone.

I have added the code at bottom on every website. The code works perfectly, but only when you touch the website before you touch the hardware-back-button on the smartphone.

If you get on a new website in the app, and you do not touch the display, the back-button works normaly.
But if you touch the website once, the the back-button gets disabled.

I have just tried, to add an input field and let them focus, but this do not help.

```
 history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
 window.onpopstate = function () {
    history.go(1);
 };
```

Comment: Why `history.pushState` and not `history.replace`?

Comment: `history.replace` do not work. `history.pushState` does work, but only when you have one times touched the website on the display.

Comment: What is the "famous back-button-problem"?